Struggling to recreate a particular categories grid layout with bootstrap 5.3
Hoping someone can put me on the right path. I’m trying to re-create this layout using bootstrap 5.3 but can’t seem to get the layout right, I also need it to be responsive so that on small devices each category is on it’s own line. I know how to create the 3x3 grid but extending the taller ones to the next line is causing me problems.
Here is the layout I'm trying to achieve:
Layout
Any suggestions?
I tried using flex wrap and changing the col types & widths.
